# Join two separate list into single list in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, ienumerable

I have two separate IEnumerable lists having dynamic values:

First list is `IEnumerable<string>` SubHeadId having data like

```
 [0]->1
 [1]->4
```

Second list is `IEnumerable<string>` SubHeadId having data like

```
 [0]->100
 [1]->233
```

I want to join these two lists into single list having data like

```
 [0]->1,100
 [1]->4,233
```

How can I join lists. Please Guide.

Thanks

Comment: You want it to be comma delimited?

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to achieve this is using the **Zip()** extension method:

```
        var firstList = new List<string>() { "1", "4" };
        var secondList = new List<string>() { "100", "233" };

        var combined = firstList.Zip(secondList, (f, s) =>  f + ", " + s ).ToList();
```

It's important to notice here that:

> If you happen to have two collections with an unequal number of elements, the Zip method will only continue to the shortest index where both elements exist. No errors will occur if the two collections are uneven.